# Odoo13: How to assign followers to a record via Controller

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

In my webform controller, I am attempting to assign email addresses entered in a webform to a given record. This is the snippet of code in my controller responsible for that

```
if 'followers' in request.params:
            raw_emails = request.httprequest.form.get('followers').split(',')
            emails = [user.strip() for user in raw_emails] 
            #emails = ['foo@bar.com', 'foo2@bar.com',..]

            for email in emails:
                follower = request.env['res.users'].search(
                    [('email', '=', email)])
                if bool(follower):
                    reg = {
                        'res_id': new_ticket.id,
                        'res_model': 'helpdesk.ticket',
                        'partner_id': follower.id
                    }
                    request.env['mail.followers'].create(reg)
                else:
                    message = "TO DO: Add {} to the system and make the user a follower of this ticket".format(
                        email)
                    new_ticket.message_post(body=message)
```

With this I get strange results i.e after entering "user A" as a follower on the webform, "user B" gets added as a follower. I'm thinking the problem might be from the wrong user record being loaded into the follower variable but I'm not seeing why. Any feedback would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [message_subscribe](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/mail/models/mail_thread.py#L2730) method to add followers to a record set.

> def message_subscribe(self, partner_ids=None, channel_ids=None, subtype_ids=None):
>     """ Main public API to add followers to a record set. Its main purpose is
>     to perform access rights checks before calling `_message_subscribe`. """

You have already an example in the account move, in [message_new](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/account/models/account_move.py#L2215) method that add a list of partners.

```
# Assign followers.
all_followers_ids = set(partner.id for partner in followers + senders + partners if is_internal_partner(partner))
move.message_subscribe(list(all_followers_ids))
```

Comment: Of course, You have just to call `message_subscribe` on a record set.

Comment: Yeah but how do I retrieve the follower ids from the raw emails submitted by a webform. It's clear to see how it can be done within a model for instance in your example above.

Comment: You can check: `self._mail_find_partner_from_emails(body_mail_addresses)`